# store offline data for querying readonly data in ipad app

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios

My app will consume a xml web service that will pull info, images and documents from the server and store it offline (docs and images are stored on a path, not in the database). I need to perform some simple queries on the offline data for viewing and browsing the offline data.

There will be no updates made on the client, the data is readonly, no need to push updates back to the server.

Should I use Core Data? Or plain XML?

What is the best solution for storing this data?

Thanks.

Comment: Well I decided to go with XML and XPath queries since this database is small and simple, won't need any updates, and this is a simpler solution for our needs. I'm going to use Matt Gallagher's xml parser wrappers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CoreData, its reliable and will give you the query abilities you want.  You could use sqllite too but CoreData will probably be simpler, especially if your data structure is not changing alot.